# How can i get the gaze raycast to pass through image but also activate gaze event

Tags: unity-game-engine, c#-4.0, raycasting

I have two canvasses. One is nested in the other. They both express a behavior when looked at. While looking at the outer canvas it works fine, but when I look at the inner canvas, the behavior of the outer canvas stops.

I pinned it down to my raycast not coming through the inner canvas.

Can someone help me or link me to a know solution?

I've tried layers but I don't quite understand them. I hope for an easier solution.

To be specific. the outer canvas closes when focus is lost, so I try to keep the object focused. When I enter the inner canvas it doesn't register it as a hit on the outer one and it starts to close.

I work specifically with HololensToolkit. It handles most of the gaze events but there doesn't seem to be an option to get multiple raycasts.

Answer (score 2):

use RaycastAll, and work with the array of returned objects instead.
for example:

```
RaycastHit[] hits;
hits = Physics.RaycastAll(transform.position, transform.forward, 100.0F);

foreach (RaycastHit hit in hits)
{
    if (hit.gameObject.tag == "menuobj")
       //do something
}
```

Comment: Can I use this while developing for a hololens? It seems a bit complex to get it to work together.

Comment: I don't see why not. You only need to give the ray starting position and direction for it to work.